# Fast/interactive development environment for python

Tags: python, time, import, module, development-environment

I just posted a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173861/should-python-imports-take-this-long) why python imports take as long as they do.  **Are there environments that don't require reinitializing modules?  If so, what are they?**

Details:  I'm trying to learn basic python syntax while using extended libraries (matplotlib, mayavi), and each time I test my code I wait (several!!) seconds for the modules to load.  There must be a faster way to do this, but I don't know what environments are well suited.  Suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like your setup is broken to me.  Look at this to see what it's doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332299/trace-python-imports.  Also maybe check the problem is with the imports using the timeit module?  And for completeness there's a builtin profiler as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script

Comment: @dementedhedgehog the answer to the question I reference suggests that some modules just take a long time to load.  I did a bit of profiling, and that seemed reasonable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ipython and pandas they might be closer to what you want.  Python does have a reload for modules but I'm not sure how well it works so anything that keeps a single python instance running and doesn't spawn python child processes is likely to fit the bill (sorry not sure what's available in that area).

http://ipython.org/

http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: Ipython seems pretty good! I like using both an editor and interactive session in tandem  (debug, record respectively), but I think once I figure out a new workflow this will be fast for development.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent.  Take a look here for editor config http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/editors.html for some thoughts on editor/ipython interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Any environment with client/server architecture (short-lived cli/gui/web-clients, long-lived computational kernels) such as https://jupyter.org/ will do.